# Make Azure Powershell cmdlet's available to team city

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, teamcity

I have installed the Azure powershell cmdlet's via the web platform installer on my build server that is running TeamCity. However, when I setup a powershell build step I get an error:

> [19:16:00][Step 2/2] Publish-AzureWebsiteProject : The term
>   'Publish-AzureWebsiteProject' is not  [19:16:00][Step 2/2] recognized
>   as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
>   [19:16:00][Step 2/2] program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
>   path was included, verify  [19:16:00][Step 2/2] that the path is
>   correct and try again.

The command works for me when I log onto the server, and the team city build agent is running under my user account. So I have no idea what's going on!

Comment: Not familiar with TeamCity (just Powershell), but you may need to import the module first?

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: import-module modulename

Comment: add `Import-Module azure` at the top of your script(s)